Does the Fréchet derivative of a function $f: X \to \mathbb R$ vanish at an extremum?
Let $X$ be a Banach space with norm $\lVert \cdot\rVert _X$ and $f: X \to \mathbb R$ a Fréchet-differentiable function, so there exists $f': X \to X^*$ such that
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h}{\lVert h \rVert_X} = 0 $$
for all $x \in X$.
Let $x$ be an extremum of $f$. Does this imply $f'(x) = 0$?
In $\mathbb R^d$ the Fréchet derivative coincides with the total differential, for which the statement is true. The standard proof shows that the gradient, defined as vector of partial derivatives, vanishes by showing that every partial derivative vanishes. On a general Banach space, this definition of a gradient is not available.
So far I was able to show that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$ f'(x) h \leq \lVert h \rVert_X \quad \text{for } h \in X \text{ with } \lVert h \rVert_X \leq \varepsilon$$
by assuming a maximum at $x$ and using  the definition of the Fréchet derivative. However, I don't think this is useful: the limit $h \to 0$ implies the trivial fact $f'(x)0 = 0$.
Is the statement true in this general setting? If yes, can you give me a hint for the proof? If no, can you give me a hint for a counterexample?

Without loss of generality, assume that $x$ is a maximum.
Since $f$ is Fréchet-differentiable, it is also Gateaux-differentiable and
$$ f'(x)h = \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{f(x+sh)-f(x)}{s}. $$
Fix a direction $h \in X$. For the one-sided limit $s \to 0^+$ we find
$$ \lim_{s\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+sh)-f(x)}{s} \geq 0 $$
as $f(x + sh) - f(x) \leq 0$ and $s \leq 0$.
For $s \to 0^-$ we find
$$ \lim_{s\to 0^-} \frac{f(x+sh)-f(x)}{s} \leq 0. $$
If the limit for $s \to 0$ exists, the two limits from the left and right must agree, therefore
$$ \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{f(x+sh)-f(x)}{s} = 0. $$
The direction $h$ was arbitrary, so $f'(x) = 0$.
